# Verbos "rir" e "explodir": afinal, eles têm conjugação ou não?

Tags: conjugações, verbos-defectivos

Há algum tempo aprendi que verbos como *rir* e *explodir* não possuem conjugação em alguns tempos verbais, mas fazendo uma pesquisa no Google, há sites que conjugam ambos os verbos em todos os tempos verbais.

Isto está correto? Ou as conjugações de fato não existem e essas informações são erradas?

Comment: Em que tempos é que diz que não têm?

Comment: Presente do indicativo é um deles.

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar Possivelmente. É bem estranho falar *Eu rio*. Até porque "rio" tem mais a ver com o substantivo "rio" (ou seja, um grande canal natural de água) do que com o presente do indicativo de "rir".

Comment: *Estou só. Com peito doendo, mas rio, pensando em você* - Amado Batista. Você está me dizendo que Amado Batista estava **errado**?! =P

Comment: Bom, acho que não. Faz parte da minha dúvida.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez _Eu rio, tu rís, ele rí, nós rímos, vós rís, eles riem_.

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar Ironicamente, escreveu _incorreto_ mal.

Comment: @someonewithpc Sim, estou cheio de ironia. =P

Comment: Ainda assim, eu enganei-me também... (Muphry's law)[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law]

Comment: @someonewithpc fez me lembrar um que escreveu "não sabes escrever português seu **ingnorante**!" ahahahahahahah

Comment: Cigano, Escolheste como correta uma resposta completamente equivocada: interpretou erradamente como defectivas as flexões irregulares assinaladas a vermelho no site referenciado. Vê os meus comentários à resposta (estão no fim).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim, os verbos [rir](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/rir) e [explodir](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/explodir) têm conjugação em todas as formas verbais.

Os verbos que só têm conjugação em algumas formas chamam-se **[verbos defectivos](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/defetivo)**. (Um exemplo é o verbo [chover](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/chover).)

> Expludo de riso sempre que vejo Porta dos Fundos! Rio-me até cair para o lado...
>
> Ris-te porquê? Acho que os vídeos deles têm imensa "falta de chá"...

Este uso é ainda confirmado por Eça de Queiroz no seu livro de 1888 [*Os Maias*](http://figaro.fis.uc.pt/queiros/obras/Maias/Maias_20001210.pdf) (página 416):

> [...] Eu ainda outro dia dizia ao Neves: «O Ega! O Ega é que era, para atirar ali na câmara a piadinha à Rochefort. Ardia Troia!»
> E imediatamente, enquanto Ega ria, contente [...]

E para *explodir* podemos até escolher entre duas versões: *expludo*, como neste exemplo do escritor mineiro Manoel Lobato,

[image]

E *explodo*, como em *A Fugitiva* de Carlos Drummond de Andrade (ênfase minha):

> ― Daqui vocês não me tiram ― respondeu-lhes a bomba. ― O primeiro que me tocar, eu ***explodo***. Talvez este tempo de verbo não exista, mas pouco estou ligando à gramática de vocês. À gramática e ao resto. Estou farta! Farta!

Comment: Acho que esta resposta tem mais lógica que a outra. Chover tem lógica não se conjugar, porque eu não posso chover. Mas eu posso-me rir e explodir também.

Comment: [`just a wafer-thin mint`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr_Creosote)?

Comment: @JorgeB. Esta resposta está certa; a outra é absurda e baseada num equívoco. Vê o meu comentário à outra. O autor interpretou as flexões a vermelho no [site que consultou](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-rir) como defectivas quando na verdade são apenas irregulares. Se o vermelho significasse defectivo, todo o [presente do indicativo do verbo *ir*](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-ir) seria defectivo!

Comment: Isto agora, com umas citações do Machado de Assis e do Eça é que ficava a matar.

Comment: Nem mais (ênfase minha): «Eu ainda outro dia dizia ao ***Neves:*** "O Ega! ***O Ega é que era,*** para atirar ali na câmara a piadinha à Rochefort. Ardia Troia!"  E imediatamente, enquanto ***Ega ria,*** contente» [(Eça de Queiroz, *Os Maias,* 1888)](http://figaro.fis.uc.pt/queiros/obras/Maias/Maias_20001210.pdf)

Comment: Vê se gostas das adições. Entretanto descobri estas [Discórdias Gramaticais](http://discordiagramatical.blogspot.pt/2012_09_01_archive.html) muito interessantes sobre os verbos defectivos. *Rir* não é nem nunca foi; já *explodir* é mais controverso.

Comment: Gosto sim, @Jacinto ! :) Mas não acho explodir nada controverso.

Comment: Vê o artigo. Há ou houve muitos bons gramático que consideravam *explodir* defectivo.

Comment: Bons gramáticos? Uns não conjugam de todo, outros aldrabam trocando com «estourar», e outros conjugam `explodo`... que selvajaria, @Jacinto! (O artigo é de facto muito bom; interessante e agradável de ler.)